# Access custom property inside ContentTemplate of custom user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following custom user control:

```
namespace MyApp.Controls {

    public partial class ArticleButton: UserControl {

        public ArticleButton () {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty;

        static ArticleButton () {

            TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ("Title", 
                typeof (String), typeof (ArticleButton));
        }

        [Description ("The name of the article."), Category ("Common Properties")]
        public String Title {
            get { return "TEST"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding `XAML`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.ArticleButton"
             Name="UC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls">
    <Button Name="button" Click="button_Click" Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=UC}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Where `defaultButtonStyle` is defined in `App.xaml` (there is more than that, but this should be sufficient):

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="defaultButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                       BorderThickness="1"
                       Padding="4,2"
                       BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                       CornerRadius="3"
                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My problem is that the property `Title` is not displayed, I tried the following which did not work either:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=UC}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ArticleButton}}}" />
```

I found lots of posts with similar issue, but none of them helped... I think the problem is that I try to access a custom property of the custom user control inside the content template of the inner button, but how to do that.

Comment: @Holt instead of `RegisterAttached` use `Register` and then `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ArticleButton}}` should work but it will not use your getter. It will call directly `GetValue` on the `TitleProperty`. You need to control your value through `DependencyProperty`

Comment: @dkozl Thanks! I am fairly new to C# and WPF so I completely messed up with dependency properties, I though that their value was retrieved using corresponding normal property getter... Actually, I have `Article` property in my `ArticleButton` and my `Title` should be `Article.Name`, is it a correct way to override `Article` setter and call `SetValue (TitleProperty, value.Name)` inside to have the desired behaviour?

Comment: When you bind `DependencyProperty` your CLR wrapper is ignored and `GetValue`/`SetValue` are called directly on `DependencyProperty`. When you `Register` your property you can pass additional `PropertyMetadata` parameter where you can set default value and/or property changed callback. Just be aware that default value of `DependencyProperty` is shared between objects so don't set it to some instance of a class - for example - as all objects will share same instance

Comment: @dkozl Thanks for your help. I'll be happy to upvote and mark an answer you'd write, because from all the "tutorial" I've read about dependency properties, none gave me that information. Actually, every tutorial I've seen just put some "standard" codes where you have a `ValueProperty` and a `Value` attributes, thus I assumed there was some kind of automatic link between those 2, which was completely wrong. You gave me more information in one comment than 10 tutorials in 50 pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up comments your 3rd `RelativeSource` binding

```
<TextBlock Text="RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ArticleButton}}"/>
```

should work fine just use `Register` instead of `RegisterAttached`. As for other bindings `{Binding Path=Title, ElementName=UC}` won't work because `ConrtrolTemplate` has its own name scope and `{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"` won't work because you don't set property against `Button` but `UserControl`.

Another problem is that you set default value against CLR wrapper and, as mentioned on this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx) page CLR wrapper is ignored and `GetValue`/`SetValue` methods are called directly for `TitleProperty`

> The WPF XAML processor uses property system methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and processing attributes that are dependency properties. This effectively bypasses the property wrappers. When you implement custom dependency properties, you must account for this behaviour and should avoid placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the property system methods GetValue and SetValue.

If you want to specify default value and/or property changed callback then when you create `DependencyProperty` there is another variant of `Register` method which also takes [`PropertyMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter where you can set these values.

Another thing you need to be aware when using dependency properties is that, because its definition is static, **default value will be shared between all instances of `ArticleButton`**. So if your type would be list or some other class and you would initialize it in `PropertyMetadata` to something different then null same instance will be shared as default value

```
public partial class ArticleButton : UserControl
{
    public ArticleButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Title",
            typeof(String),
            typeof(ArticleButton),
            new PropertyMetadata("Test", TitlePropertyChanged));

    private static void TitlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as ArticleButton).TitlePropertyChanged(e);
    }

    private void TitlePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something when property changed value
    }

    public String Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```